# MySQL Update Table Column using Query From Second Table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that share five columns.  No keys in common though.

```
Pricing Table:
* Type
* Platform
* Term
* Engine
* Price

Products Table:
* Type
* Platform
* Term
* Engine
* Price
```

I need to update the Price field in the Product table using the Price field from the Products table.

In order to get the one specific row, I need to filter to where Products.Type = Pricing.Type, Products.Platform = Pricing.Platform, Products.Term = Pricing.Term, Products.Engine = Pricing.Engine

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?   I'm not a DBA, so any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: "I need to update the Price field in the Product table using the Price field from the Products table" Are you sure that's what you mean, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Also, would you mind indicating what you're using to access the database? PHP, C, Python, pure SQL, etc

Comment: "No keys in common though." Clearly (and luckily) that's not true. It just so happens that your key spans 4 columns.

Comment: but tables are the same! why the heck did you split it?

Comment: Ben:  This was using MySQL/MariaDB.  And both tables have a Price Field.  Price.Price is used to update Products.Price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your product table using:

```
`UPDATE product p
INNER JOIN price pr ON pr.Type = p.Type 
AND pr.Platform = p.Platform 
AND pr.Term = p.Term 
AND pr.Engine = p.Engine
SET p.price = pr.price;`
```

Comment: I actually asked a DBA friend yesterday and he gave the same answer as above.   Marking as the answer.  Thanks